# .htaccess apache 2.2 to 2.4 update

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Our host has recently updated their apache server from 2.2 to 2.4 and now we keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error, our error log reads "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters".

Our .htAccess file looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/.*$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test.php$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^phonegapFunction.php$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9æøå]*)\/?(\w*)\/?(.*)$ /app.php?team=$1&page=$2&value=$3 [L]
```

Our host said we need to update the .htaccess file to apache 2.4 specification, but we are having problems doing that, so hopefully someone here can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those comments actually part of your htaccess file?

Comment: What @JonLin said, .htaccess comments need to be on their own line.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html - Apache documentation on upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4

Comment: @JonLin Yes those are part of the htaccess file, but we have tried removing them and nothing changes regarding the error message.

Comment: @Sammitch As I wrote above, yes those are part of the htaccess file, but we have tried removing them and now also moving them to their own line, nothing changes regarding the error message.

Comment: @Lumberjack We have tried looking at the documentation, but can't really find something that relates to our specific problem though..

Comment: Then I honestly can't see anything wrong with any of your RewriteConds. I'd suggest commenting them out one at a time until the error goes away simply to isolate which of the three it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get in both Apache 2.2 and 2.4

With .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/.*$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test.php$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^phonegapFunction.php$ #allows to access views folder and everything in it.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9æøå]*)\/?(\w*)\/?(.*)$ /app.php?team=$1&page=$2&value=$3 [L]
```

This is the error I get in the error logs, for both versions:

```
/var/www/localhost/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

But if I remove the comments:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test.php$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^phonegapFunction.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9???]*)\/?(\w*)\/?(.*)$ /app.php?team=$1&page=$2&value=$3 [L]
```

No errors and I can get routed to app.php just fine.